# How expensive is creating class instance? (performance considerations)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In C#, how expensive it is to create a new class instance?

I'm speaking in context of using C# in unity3d. Meaning that stuff continuously gets called many times per second.

In C++, generally speaking (while making games) you may want to reuse anything you created with `new`/smart pointers, you would want to keep allocated resizeable buffers/lists/fifos and you may want to avoid that uses dynamic memory allocation (and stick to local variables) if code is getting performance critical.

So, what is the recommended way to do it in C#? Is it a very bad idea to create a  new `List`, return it from the function and then "forget" about it, never using it again?

P.S. I'm aware of profiling and "premature optimizations", but I'd like to know some generic guidelines for the language before I (possibly) make a big mess because I used the wrong approach.

Comment: write the code, check if it works, if you face performance problems try to fix it.

Comment: I can't emphasize this enough... Concentrate on the *correctness* of your code. Like @dotctor said, get it right, then worry about performance.

Comment: @dotctor While what you guys say makes sense, I can't help but remember that one time where I managed to speed up program 3 times by reusing a container instead of keeping it as local variable. Also, I still need to know difference in cost of object allocation compared to C++. In C++ cost of dynamic allocation is relatively high. In C# it is unclear.

Comment: there is 2 high cost actions in OOP, Object creation, Message passing. but you cannot do anything without them. Just write the code and if you see that there is a performance problem on some parts, profile them and then change the mechanism of object creation there. do not try to micro optimize or premature optimizations before writing code, these are not part of analysis or design, these problems will be solved in testing and maintenance

Comment: In general, allocation is usually faster in C#. But that's just tiny part of the problem - there's associated costs with any new object, and those can bite you quite easily (the more objects you have on the heap, the more often and more expensive collections are). Fix your performance issue when it *actually appears*. There really isn't much of general advice to be given - it depends on how often it happens, how much data is in there, how many alternate options you have... it's usually quite easy to rewrite code for performance - test the simple version first, optimize later.

Comment: I can't give you any numbers, but one thing that reusing objects (object pooling) would do is reducing pressure on the garbage collector. This can reduce GC spikes and/or make them less frequent. I'd start by looking for more efficient algorithms, of course.

Comment: I hereby request examples of "not so broad" phrasing of the question from all the people that put this on hold. Problem looks incredibly specific to me. "How object creation cost in C# compares to said cost in C++". If there's a better way to ask the question, I'd like to see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember reading a fun post [Performance numbers in the pub](http://ayende.com/blog/4811/performance-numbers-in-the-pub) by Ayendy Rahien.

> How many CLR objects can you create in one second?

And here was the result back in 2011

> Created 7,715,305 in 00:00:01

Jokes aside. Create is pretty cheap operation but GC is not. So while you can create really many objects, it is the collect that will hurt performance. So a rule of objects reuse can apply to C# as well.

I'd assume, but can be wrong, implementation of a *new* operator is located in JIT

- [aloc.h](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/4cf8a6b082d9bb1789facd996d8265d3908757b2/src/jit/alloc.h)
- [aloc.cpp](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/4cf8a6b082d9bb1789facd996d8265d3908757b2/src/jit/alloc.cpp)

As usual, avoid premature optimisation till you need it.

Comment: Nice link. 7 million objects per second is incredibly unimpressive (even in 2011), but (after reading through comments in original blog) it looks like it was possible to get between 2 to 4 hundred millions of allocations per second, which is more like it.